# Is this the only way to shorten a String?

Tags: swift, string, function, character

I am currently learning to program without any programming experience and Swift is my first language to learn. When coming to make a function that executes shortening a fullName, there is one solution that I looked up:

```
func shortNameFromName(name:String) -> String {
    let shortName = name.lowercased()
    let vowelRange = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")
    if let nameRange = shortName.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowelRange) {
        return shortName.substring(from: nameRange.lowerBound)
    }

    return "shortName"
}
```

I am confused at this stage, why is it "aeiou" there and is it an only way to do?

Any shorter solution for this?

Comment: Where's your code attempting to access characters of a string? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: `CharacterSet(charactersIn:)` is *not* for accessing characters of a String, you misunderstood that part. It is just a character set - a group of unique characters held up in a data structure. `CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")` means "this is a group of characters composed of these 5 characters".

Comment: according to your question title `let arr = Array("aeiou".characters)
arr[1]
`

Comment: @Moritz Thank so much for your help, yeah you are right, i am so confused at this stage, this is a part of a shortNameforName function that asked to make.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Thanks Salman, i will try it.

Comment: @rmaddy I am so sorry for the very unclear question. I just edit it to make it clearer.